# How to change image of a button with variable image name?

Tags: ios, swift, imagebutton

I want to change the image of a button programmatically. The only way I now is this:

```
button.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "imagename", for: .normal))
```

But now i want to use a variable `imagename`. Is there any way to do this? In the end i have a folder of images and than i collect a image with using a function. The last row of the function is that i set the imagename to the name of the collected image. I know how to write this function. But i don't know how to set the image of the button with a variable imagename. 
I hope you understand my problem and anybody can help me.

Here the code:

```
 var imageArroy = [UIImage(named:"car1"),UIImage(named:"car2")]

//scrollview
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageArroy.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

    var imagename: String = imageArroy[indexPath.row])

    cell.car.setImage(UIImage.init(named: imagename)!, for: .normal)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: What is variable image name? Just some variable of type `String` or `UIImage`?

Comment: I used imagename as just a variable. Is it better to use it of type String?

Comment: So do you have array of images? Add some code to your question to better understanding

Comment: i added the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have an array of elements, you can get certain element by specifing its index

```
array[index]
       ^ Int
```

*... note that index of first element is 0, not 1*

---

So in `cellForRowAt` you can get certain `UIImage?` by getting image from your array on index equal to row of current index path. Don't forget to unwrap it

```
cell.car.setImage(imageArroy[indexPath.row]!, for: .normal)
```